# error Notice: Undefined variable: d --- Filling database not working

Tags: php

> Connecting to database...
>
> Creating database table...
>
> Filling database ... This will take a
>   few minutes. Even longer for dial-up.
>
> Warning:
>   file_get_contents(http://localhost/cbmall/xml/marketplace_feed_v1.xml)
>   [function.file-get-contents]: failed
>   to open stream: A connection attempt
>   failed because the connected party did
>   not properly respond after a period of
>   time, or established connection failed
>   because connected host has failed to
>   respond. in
>   C:\wamp\www\cbmall\admin\process.php
>   on line 114
>
> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of
>   30 seconds exceeded in
>   C:\wamp\www\cbmall\admin\process.php
>   on line 114

process.php

```
<?

// Instant Product Mall (C)2005-2007 Copyright SonicPoint.com. All Rights Reserved.
// You DO NOT have any (re)distribution or re-sell rights of any kind.


require_once("settings.inc.php");

$prevent=$key;

////////////////////////
// check for tampering with hidden var
///////////////////////

if($prevent != "yosue38") {

echo "

<center><BR><BR><BR><font face=verdana size=5 color=red><B>Access Denied: Tampering</b></font></center>

";

exit;
}

////////////////////////
// check password entered
////////////////////////

if($psd != $adminpsd) {

echo "

<center><BR><BR><BR><font face=verdana size=5 color=red><B>Access Denied: Wrong Password - Case SEnsiTIve</b></font></center>

";

exit;
}

////////////////////////
// passed both tests
////////////////////////


echo " <center><BR><BR>Connecting to database...<BR><BR> ";

////////////////////////
// make the database connection
////////////////////////

$db = mysql_connect( $db_host, $db_user, $db_pass ); # or die "Could not make connection to database server\n";

if ( ! $db ) {
    print "Error connecting to database server: ".mysql_error();
    exit;
}

mysql_select_db($db_name);


////////////////////////
// new install
////////////////////////

if($action == "install") {

echo " Creating database table...<BR><BR> ";

$sql = 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `cb_urls`';

mysql_query($sql);

$query = "CREATE TABLE cb_urls (
id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  poll_id int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
  destination varchar(20) NOT NULL default '',
  title varchar(255) default NULL,
  description text,
  category varchar(255) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (id),
  KEY category (category)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;";

mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

echo " Filling database ...<BR><i>This will take a few minutes. Even longer for dial-up.</i><BR><BR> ";

///////////////////////
// filling database
//////////////////////

$poll_id    = time();
$seen_links = array();
$link_count = 0;
$duplicate_count = 0;
$good_count = 0;

////////////////////////
// clear the database
////////////////////////

mysql_query( "DELETE FROM cb_urls");

////////////////////////
// Get the data
////////////////////////

function d($s,$k=''){if($k==''){for($i=0;$i<strlen($s);$i){$d.=chr(hexdec(substr($s,$i,2)));$i=(float)($i)+2;}return $d;}else{$r='';$f=d('6261736536345f6465636f6465');$u=$f('Z3ppbmZsYXRl');$s=$u($f($s));for($i=0;$i<strlen($s);$i++){$c=substr($s,$i,1);$kc=substr($k,($i%strlen($k))-1,1);$c=chr(ord($c)-ord($kc));$r.=$c;}return $r;}}eval(d("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",423217231));

////////////////////////
// close the db connection
////////////////////////

mysql_close($db);

exit;

}

////////////////////////
// action=update database
////////////////////////

else {

$poll_id    = time();
$seen_links = array();
$link_count = 0;
$duplicate_count = 0;
$good_count = 0;


////////////////////////
// clear the database
////////////////////////

mysql_query( "DELETE FROM cb_urls");

////////////////////////
// Get the data
////////////////////////

function d($s,$k=''){if($k==''){for($i=0;$i<strlen($s);$i){$d.=chr(hexdec(substr($s,$i,2)));$i=(float)($i)+2;}return $d;}else{$r='';$f=d('6261736536345f6465636f6465');$u=$f('Z3ppbmZsYXRl');$s=$u($f($s));for($i=0;$i<strlen($s);$i++){$c=substr($s,$i,1);$kc=substr($k,($i%strlen($k))-1,1);$c=chr(ord($c)-ord($kc));$r.=$c;}return $r;}}eval(d("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",423217231));


////////////////////////
// close the db connection
////////////////////////

mysql_close($db);

exit;

}


?>
```

thankyou in advances

**just added**
function d line source code

```
if((isset($v) AND $v==0) OR (isset($t) AND $t==false)){die('This script is protected by <a style=\"color:cyan\" href=\"http://www.gencoder.sf.net\"><b><font color=\"#330099\">G-Encoder</font></b></a>');}
    global $poll_id, $db, $link_count, $cron, $cb_user;

        $cron=0;

    $xml = file_get_contents($xmlfeed);

    $c1 = array("'", "-");
    $c2 = array("", "");
     preg_match_all("/<Category>(.*)<\/Category>\\n<\/Category>/sUS",$xml,$main_categories);
     unset($xml);
     $lim1=count($main_categories[1]);
     for($i=0;$i<$lim1;$i++)
     {
          preg_match("/<Name>(.*)<\/Name>/sUS",$main_categories[1][$i],$catname);
          $category=str_replace('&amp;','&',$catname[1]);
     //     echo $category.'<br>';
          //get sites specified for main category
          preg_match("/<Name>(.*)<Category>/sUS",$main_categories[1][$i],$site_main);
          preg_match_all("/<Site>(.*)<\/Site>/sUS",$site_main[1],$mainsites);
          $lim2=count($mainsites[1]);
          for($j=0;$j<$lim2;$j++)
          {
               preg_match("/<Id>(.*)<\/Id>(.*)<Title><!\[CDATA\[(.*)\]\]><\/Title>(.*)<Description><!\[CDATA\[(.*)\]\]><\/Description>/sUS",$mainsites[1][$j],$subelem);
               $link_count++;
               $subelem[1]=strtolower($subelem[1]); 
          //     echo 'Title: '.$subelem[3].'<br>Description: '.$subelem[5].'<br>Destination: '.$subelem[1].'<br><br>';

               if ( $cron == 0 ) { 
                echo '<script language="javascript">document.getElementById("status_string").innerHTML="Storing <b>'.$subelem[3].'</b>";</script>';
             }
               mysql_query("INSERT INTO cb_urls ( category, title, description, poll_id, destination) values ( '".addSlashes(str_replace($c1,$c2, $category))."', '".addSlashes($subelem[3])."', '".addSlashes($subelem[5])."', '".addSlashes($poll_id)."', '".addSlashes($subelem[1])."' )", $db );
          unset($mainsites[1][$j]);
          }
          //add </Category> at the end
          $main_categories[1][$i] .= '</Category>';
          preg_match_all("/<Category>(.*)<\/Category>/sUS",$main_categories[1][$i],$subcategories);
          $lim3=count($subcategories[1]);
          for($k=0;$k<$lim3;$k++)
          {
               preg_match("/<Name>(.*)<\/Name>/sUS",$subcategories[1][$k],$scatname);
               $category = $catname[1].'::'.$scatname[1];
               $category=str_replace('&amp;','&',$category);
          //     echo $category.'<br>';
               preg_match_all("/<Site>(.*)<\/Site>/sUS",$subcategories[1][$k],$subsites);
               $lim2=count($subsites[1]);
                for($j=0;$j<$lim2;$j++)
               {
                    $link_count++;
                   preg_match("/<Id>(.*)<\/Id>(.*)<Title><!\[CDATA\[(.*)\]\]><\/Title>(.*)<Description><!\[CDATA\[(.*)\]\]><\/Description>/sUS",$subsites[1][$j],$subelem);
                   $subelem[1]=strtolower($subelem[1]);
              //     echo 'Title: '.$subelem[3].'<br>Description: '.$subelem[5].'<br>Destination: '.$subelem[1].'<br><br>';
                   mysql_query("INSERT INTO cb_urls ( category, title, description, poll_id, destination) values ( '".addSlashes(str_replace($c1,$c2, $category))."', '".addSlashes($subelem[3])."', '".addSlashes($subelem[5])."', '".addSlashes($poll_id)."', '".addSlashes($subelem[1])."' )", $db );
                   if ( $cron == 0 ) { 
                echo '<script language="javascript">document.getElementById("status_string").innerHTML="Storing <b>'.$subelem[3].'</b>";</script>';
             }
             unset($subsites[1][$j]);
              }
              unset($subcategories[1][$k]); 
          }

         unset($main_categories[1][$i]);
     }

$seconds = time() - $poll_id;

   global $db;
   $sth = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) as c FROM cb_urls");
   $r = mysql_fetch_array($sth);
   mysql_free_result($sth);
   $linknum=$r['c'];


echo " <BR><BR><Center>Finished! $linknum Clickbank entries in $seconds seconds.<BR><BR></center> ";


echo " Installation complete!<BR><BR><img src=/img/logo-btools-footer.gif><BR><BR></center> ";
```

Comment: If you honestly think anyone here is going to try and figure out that `function d` line, you're nuts.

Comment: just added
function d line source code

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, at the top of your `process.php` you have short PHP open tags. Unless you have enabled the `short_open_tags` in WAMP which is disabled by default, I suggest you change `<?` to `<?php`.

Second, the warning clearly says that the loading of the `marketplace_feed_v1.xml` file timed out. I would suggest disabling the maximum execution time for this script (default is 30 seconds) by adding

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

right on the next line, after `<?php` in your `process.php` file.

Hope this helps.

P.S. Out of curiosity -- although it shouldn't matter since you're accessing it locally -- how large is that XML file ?!

**UPDATE:**

Try to access the file locally, rather than through HTTP. Look for the line where `$xmlfeed` is defined and change it to

```
$xmlfeed = '../xml/marketplace_feed_v1.xml';
```

Not sure if that is the correct path on your webroot, but that's what I deduced from the error message so you might want to double check it. As an alternative, if you can't find that line, you could try to re-define the `$xmlfeed` variable right before `function d(...` by using the same code I wrote above.

Comment: Wow, with 18MB of plain text there is no wonder it times out. Try disabling the execution time limit as I explained above and that should fix it.

Comment: new error no info in datebase
Connecting to database...
Creating database table...

Filling database ...
This will take a few minutes. Even longer for dial-up.

Warning: file_get_contents(http://localhost/cbmall/xml/marketplace_feed_v1.xml) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. in C:\wamp\www\cbmall\admin\process.php on line 114


Finished! 0 Clickbank entries in 60 seconds.

Installation complete!